# Create table schema and load data in bigquery table using source google drive

Tags: google-bigquery

I am creating table using google drive as a source and google sheet as a format.

I have selected "Drive" as a value for create table from. For file Format, I selected Google Sheet.

Also I selected the Auto Detect Schema and input parameters.
 Its creating the table but the first row of the sheet is also loaded as a data instead of table fields.

[image]

Kindly tell me what I need to do to get the first row of the sheet as a table column name not as a data.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful if you could include a screenshot of the top few rows of the file you're trying to upload at least to see the data types you have in there. BigQuery, at least as of when this response was composed, cannot differentiate between column names and data rows if both have similar datatypes while schema auto detection is used. For instance, if your data looks like this:

```
headerA, headerB
row1a, row1b
row2a, row2b
row3a, row3b
```

BigQuery would not be able to detect the column names (at least automatically using the UI options alone) since all the headers and row data are Strings. The "Header rows to skip" option would not help with this. 
Schema auto detection should be able to detect and differentiate column names from data rows when you have different data types for different columns though.

Comment: I can confirm that I have been able to reproduce this behavior. Skipping the first row (as proposed in the other answer) is a good complement with manually adding the schema in order to avoid including the fileds row as data, but does not guarantee that it detects that row as the fields names when using autodetect.

Answer (score 0):

You have an option to skip header row in Advanced options. Simply put 1 as the number of rows to skip (your first row is where your header is). It will skip the first row and use it as the values for your header.

[image]

Comment: But would this make the skipped row the header of the columns? I think this just skips the specified number of rows while the question asks about assigning the first row values as column names.

Comment: It does actually use the row you skipped to create header

Comment: Can you please try it on the example file I provided in my response (all fields/headers of type String)? I just tried it and it was not able to detect the header no matter if you use the skip option or not.